# Update the view model in the xaml.cs file to add some logic in mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm using mvvm for my application and I'm use binding to bind the items and change automaticly  when there are some changes in my view but in some cases I want to add some logic and then send it to the view model. for example:

```
        private string _children;
        public string Children
        {
            get
            {
                return _children;
            }
            set
            {
                _children= value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Children));
            }

        }
```

And my view:

```
                <TextBox Name="Child"></TextBox>
                <Button Content="Add" Click="Add_Children"/>
                <ListView Name="ChildrenList">

                </ListView>
```

```
        private string children
        private void Add_Children(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string name = Child.Text;
            ChildrenList.Items.Add(name);
            children += name;
        }
```

I want to send the children field to my view model, But I can't because I don't any access to the view model in xaml.cs file.

This example is not my exact problem. In this case I could just use a list instead of a string, But
I just wanted to ask a general question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the best way to achieve this in `MVVM`, but you can access your `ViewModel` like this:

**In your xaml.cs file:**

Declare variable
`YourViewModel vm;`

Add this declaration to constructor
`this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(OnLoaded);`

Create this method

```
public void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
       vm = this.DataContext as TableDrawingsViewModel;
}
```

And then tou can access tour `ViewModel` instance by using `this.vm`

Comment: Is this TableDrawingsViewModel all the time?

Comment: There should be just one ViewModel for each View, so yes.